# Related to maven release project

Tags: java, maven, github, jenkins

Facing the issue of **scm connection or developerConnection must** be specified when making the maven release of project.

```
15:35:28 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
15:35:28 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:35:28 [INFO] Total time:  23.550 s
15:35:28 [INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-23T10:05:28Z
15:35:28 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:35:28 Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
15:35:28 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project cah-process: Missing required setting: scm connection or developerConnection must be specified. -> [Help 1]
15:35:28 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project cah-process: Missing required setting: scm connection or developerConnection must be specified.
```

1. changes the scm repository url on github.
2. add the url in  tag like this.

> https://github.com/internal/process
>         scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/internal/process.git
>         scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/internal/process.git
>         HEAD

commands we have tried to execute for release:

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"
mvn release:prepare -Dresume=true
mvn release:prepare -Dresume=false
mvn release:clean release:prepare
mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true
```

but still the same issue like **scm connection or developerConnection**

but when we tried to compile the project using mvn clean install then it working.

Comment: Add as much as possible informations as text not as screenshot

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full text of the error message.

Comment: Can you remove the `ssh://` from your URLs? This is what I use and which works (with replaced user and repo names): `scm:git:git@github.com:internal/process.git`. Note that the first `/` after `github.com` also needs to be changed to `:`.

Comment: To do a release via maven-release-plugin it is necessary to have scm connections configuration otherwise the release can not being made...Also to do a release you have to call `mvn release:prepare release:perform`...

Comment: The removing of `ssh` is not really the problem.. take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp also add the logging output during the run it shows some problems if there are some... Also I would strongly recommend to configure the most recent version of maven-release-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)

Comment: I did corrections in my file as according to you git repo "github.com/khmarbaise/smpp "  but still my problem not resolved. still facing the issue.

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project cah-process: Missing required setting: scm connection or developerConnection must be specified. -> [Help 1]
 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :cah-process